# How to select multiple rows by primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE
(`PRIMARY_KEY`= `VALUE1`) OR
(`PRIMARY_KEY`= `VALUE2`) OR
(`PRIMARY_KEY`= `VALUE3`) OR
(`PRIMARY_KEY`= `VALUE4`) OR
(`PRIMARY_KEY`= `VALUE5`) OR ...
```

This works. But is there a faster way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE primary_key IN (value1, value2, ...)
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the `value in (list)` construct is not faster, **but the SQL-code will be much easier to read/understand** once someone needs to maintain the code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `TABLE` 
WHERE `PRIMARY_KEY` in( `VALUE1`
                       , `VALUE2`
                       , `VALUE3`
                       , `VALUE4`
                       , `VALUE5`
                      )
```

**Updated:** Rewritten to reflect the feedback from the comments.

Comment: I think it's a common fallacy that `in()` is faster that chained `OR` statements (or vice-versa).  It's just simply less typing.  I tried to find some references to this, but getting a useful Google result where "in" and "or" are vital keywords is difficult =P

Comment: @Peter Bailey: You are probably right if/when we are talking about DB performance, and I was debating with myself if I should should use "will or might in the answer above ...  , **BUT** consider programmer and DBA performance (in head scratching hours) when maintaining / optimizing that code .. On the other hand, it will be much easier for the optimizer (human or MySQL) to relize that an index should be used (moot in this case, PRIMARY_KEY is PK)

Comment: @Peter Bailey: That was my first thought when I read the answers too, so I tried it with Oracle 10g, and **execution plan is the same**. I assume that other DBs are going to handle it the same way. @lexu: It is certainly easier for humans to read, and I would always do it that way. Non-human optimizers should be fine with both ways, though :)

Comment: @Peter Bailey & @Peter Lang: rewrote my answer, thx for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN` keyword to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PRIMARY_KEY IN (VALUE1, VALUE2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE
(`PRIMARY_KEY`IN( `VALUE1`,`VALUE2`,`VALUE3`,`VALUE4`,`VALUE5`) )
```